# Converting dataframe to json in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have dataframe like this:

`dis   equip   siteRef        installed
RTU-1   m   r:153c-699a HQ   d:2005-06-01
RTU-2   m   r:153c-699a HQ   d:999-07-12`

I need a json in the format:

```
`{
  "meta": {"ver":"2.0", "projName":"test"},
  "cols":[
  {"name":"dis", "dis":"Equip Name"},
  {"name":"equip"},
  {"name":"siteRef"},
  {"name":"installed"}
 ],
  "rows":[
   {"dis":"RTU-1", "equip":"m:", "siteRef":"r:153c-699a HQ", 
     "installed":"d:2005-06-01"},
   {"dis":"RTU-2", "equip":"m:", "siteRef":"r:153c-699a HQ", 
     "installed":"d:999-07-12"}
 ]
}`
```

Can I do that using inbuild pandas.to_json? I tried all orient option but couldn't find the one I needed

Comment: Your json output has more data than given in the data frame. Is it that way? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to build all the meta-stuff yourself, along with the `rows`-wrapper, but I was able to achieve what you provided with `to_json(orient="records")`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"dis": "RTU-1", "equip": "m", "siteRef": "r:153c-699a HQ", "installed": "d:2005-06-01"},
    {"dis": "RTU-2", "equip": "m", "siteRef": "r:153c-699a HQ", "installed": "d:999-07-12"}])
df.to_json(orient="records")
```

Result:

```
'[{"dis":"RTU-1","equip":"m","installed":"d:2005-06-01","siteRef":"r:153c-699a HQ"},{"dis":"RTU-2","equip":"m","installed":"d:999-07-12","siteRef":"r:153c-699a HQ"}]'
```

... which is the "one object-per-record" format you specified, no?